# Why can I no longer give things to the pig king?

Tags: dont-starve

In *Don't Starve*, you are oftentimes able encounter a small village of pig men. In said village, there is a Pig King.

The Pig King will give you gold in exchange for certain items and food. The *Don't Starve* wikia says he should give me 2-8 gold ore in exchange for my red and blue gems, however, he is no longer taking any items from me.

**Why can't I give the Pig King anymore stuff?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pig King doesn't accept [Gravedigger Items](http://dont-starve-game.wikia.com/wiki/Gravedigger_Items) that are used in recipes, including red and blue gems, as well as nightmare fuel, gears and amulets. Only items that aren't used in recipes (labelled in the Wiki as Trinkets), like gnomes, marbles, etc. are accepted by him.

Comment: Ah, well... My mistake then.

Comment: And, aside from gravedigger items, you can also give him other stuff like pig skins or meats (even dried monster jerky), which only yield 1 gold, but are renewable.